# I want a 'Text Field' in a folder that is within a document library - Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am rather new to sharepoint and have been lucky enough to find the answer to all my questions with research.  I have no found the answer to this question yet.... How do I add a text field WITHIN a folder that is WITHIN a document library.  Example:  I want to put instructions for upload within a specific folder.  I tried to to the 'edit page' --> add text, but the text shows up at the top of ALL folders within that library and I just want it in one.  Thank you for your assistance!

Kind regards, 
Lanie

Answer (score 0):

You can manage visibility of your message using JavaScript as below.

Don't directly add your message in text field; instead click of the text field you have added, and click "Edit HTML Source" in ribbon bar as highlighted in below image.

[image]

Then paste below code in newly opened window:

**(Don't forget to replace "Your Message" and "FolderNameInWhichMessageToBeShown" in below code)**

```
<div id="MyCustomMessage">
    Your Message 
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    if(decodeURIComponent(document.URL).indexOf('FolderNameInWhichMessageToBeShown') == -1)
    {
        document.getElementById('MyCustomMessage').style.display = 'none'
    } 
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById('MyCustomMessage').style.display = 'block'
    }
</script>
```

Click "OK" and Save your page.

Comment: FANTASTIC!  It worked like a charm.  Now my question would be how to you EDIT the text i.e.  If I add a line inbetween the two points, they show up in other folders.  SO how to I add a line in java so it knows I want a space inbetween those two lines?

Comment: **What I understand is, you want message to be multi-lined. 
If this is the case, you need to use HTML tag in message div, it can be set like-**
`<div id="MyCustomMessage" style="display: block">
 Your Second Line Message <br/>
 Your Second Line Message <br/>
 Your Third Line Message 
</div>` **No any changes are required in JavaScript**

Comment: Because this is the HTML source for the entire library, I'm assuming you can't display different messages at the top of each folder?